# What's the best way to join and leave pubnub channels dynamically

Tags: chat, pubnub

I'm working on this chat type scenario and the need is to track presence -

Note: every client in this scenario will subscribe with option withPresence set to true.

Pubnub cofig-
Max announce is set to 1, so i rely on interval event type.

phoneA will ask server for a channel name, Server will generate a unique channel name (lets say ch-chat) and return to PhoneA.

Now both phoneA and server will add the channel to their own channel groups (cg-phoneA and cg-server)and subscribe to their own channel groups.

PhoneA shares the channel name with phoneB and phoneC and they both add the channel to their own channel groups, cg-phoneB and cg-phoneC. Bkth B and C are also subscribed to their own channel group.

Now,
When phoneA removes channel (ch-chat) from its own channel group (cg-phoneA), server does not gets phobeA in leave uuids list of interval event. But after ~5mins server gets timeout event for phoneA.

What i want -
phoneA should present in the leave list of the interval event since phoneA removed the channel from its own channel group, theres no way it should be subscribed anymore to it.

Comment: I think I missed this suggestion - 
https://www.pubnub.com/docs/presence/presence-webhooks#:~:text=The%20standard%20way%20for%20PubNub,recommend%20using%20Presence%20Webhooks%20instead.

presence webhooks seems more scalable and easy to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Presence Modes: Announce vs Interval

One issue is that your *Announce Max* setting of 1 will mute all presence events except for `state-change`. In other words, you are in *Interval* mode all the time for every channel. Read more about [Presence Event Modes here](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/presence/presence-events#presence-event-modes).

When channels are added to a channel group, you should receive the join event (if in *Announce* mode and not *Interval*), if you are subscribed to the channel group `withPresence: true`. Be sure you want to receive presence events for all channels in that channel group though. You can create a second channel group for channels you do not need to receive presence events.

### Managing Channel Groups

As for managing Channels in your Channel Groups, be sure that only your Server is the one adding/removing channels for all channel groups. This has to do with security when you enable Access Manager (and everyone should be enabled/implementing Access Manager to protect your keys and your users).

### Presence Webhooks

As for Presence Webhooks, this is the best way for your Server to monitor presence events. It is not recommended that you subscribe from your server. It will be difficult/complex to scale to multiple server instances. This is why the Presence Webhooks exist. And your clients and POST directly to the Server for any requests it needs, like your "generate new channel" request. And your server and reply to those posts and then `publish` all further updates to the channel the client is subscribed to.

### Channel Naming Conventions

It is great that you are using "generated channel names" (like a UUID pattern) but prefix your channels to identity them to provide a means to group them with pattern match through regex. I would recommend using a "dot" so that you can also potentially take advantage of PubNub wildcarding features:

- PubNub Functions channel binding
- Presence ACLs (custom presence channel behavior configuration)
- Access Manager wildcard granting
- Wildcard Subscribe

For example:

- `chat.4849-ut83-83jd...`
- `notify.tuy7-87er-27fn...`

*NOTE: Channel Groups do not allow "dots" in the name and do not have any wildcarding features.*

Comment: Thanks for the detailed solution, I realised that webhooks are simpler and scalable than subscribing to clients presence events on the server. 
Now, I make server manipulate channel groups on behalf of client and webhooks works great for async processing of presence events.